# QR decomposition in C++ by LAPACK

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, lapack

I have recently installed a new library for matrix calculation in C++, called [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/). I am beginner in this field and wanted to test its application in QR decomposition by using the `dgeqrf` function. I prepared this simple code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <lapacke.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a[4] = {0, 2, 2, -1};

    int m=2;
    int n=2;
    int info = 0;
    int lda = m;
    int lwork = n;
    double *work;
    double *tau;

    dgeqrfp_(&m, &n, a, &lda, tau, work, &lwork, &info);
}
```

I built it without error but when I tried to run it, it didn't work. I got these warning messages:

```
D:\c++ code\lllll\main.cpp|15|warning: 'tau' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
D:\c++ code\lllll\main.cpp|15|warning: 'work' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
```

I don't know what's the problem but I think my definition of the `dgeqrf` function is wrong.

Also, the `dgeqrf` is a `void` function. I need to save its result (Q matrix) into an another matrix and use it in my calculation.

Does anyone have an idea about it?

Comment: The `tau` and the `work` parameters are supposed to be preallocated arrays. For more information (especially about the required lengths of said arrays), please refer to the docs.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, But I couldn't find information about how I can determine the parameters in a simple c++ example for "dgesqr" function in docs or even in the Internet.

Comment: Alright, alright, I'll look for a dupe and write an answer if I don't find one. Gimme a few minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [the docs](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dd/d9a/group__double_g_ecomputational_ga5dc72a0f55ff4c08f1a3596f56e04aaa.html#ga5dc72a0f55ff4c08f1a3596f56e04aaa), `TAU` and `WORK` are supposed to be arrays the function can work on.

In particular, `WORK` shall be an array of `double` and have (at least) length `LWORK`, it is used as internal temporary memory.

`TAU` is an array used to output the elementary reflectors of the QR decomposition and shall have length (at least) `min(n,m)`.

So your complete call would look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <lapacke.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double a[4] = {0,2,2,-1};
    int m=2;
    int n=2;
    int info = 0;
    int lda = m;
    int lwork = n;
    double work[2];
    double tau[2];
    dgeqrfp_(&m, &n, a, &lda, tau, work, &lwork, &info);
}
```